# Where to set BASEDIR with Tomcat 7 installed with Homebrew

Tags: java, tomcat, solr, tomcat7, solr4

On my Mac, I have Tomcat set up with solr 1.4 and solr 3.5 under /Library/Home in the following locations:

```
/Library/Tomcat/Home
```

where /Home is symlinked to /Library/Tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.32

```
/Library/Tomcat/Home/webapps/solr
```

with individual cores under

```
/Library/Tomcat/solr
```

Java is installed at

```
/Library/Java/Home
```

where /home is symlinked to /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home

I was having issues getting Solr 4.10.4 running in conjunction with that Tomcat, and I'm using Homebrew for my MySQL and PHP, so I thought I'd try using tomcat7 and solr4  with homewbrew. So this installed tomcat7 to

```
/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat7/7.0.61
```

The problem arises when I try to start Tomcat using

```
/usr/local/Cellar/tomcat7/7.0.61/libexec/bin/startup.sh
```

I get this error:

> The BASEDIR environment variable is not defined This environment
>   variable is needed to run this program

I've been searching around, and I've seen various suggestions for fixing this, but I can 't get any to work.  First, I'm not sure if this is supposed to be the same as CATALINA_HOME. I have JAVA_HOME and CATALINA_HOME set in my profile (I did change CATALINA_HOME to /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat7/7.0.61/libexec). I tried also setting BASEDIR in my profile to the same path as CATALINA_HOME, but still get the same error when I try to start tomcat.

I don't remember having to do this with my previous installation of Tomcat 6 and Solr 3. What does BASEDIR need to be set to, and where exactly do I set it?

Thanks.